# Is require.main.filename supported in webpack when targeting node?

Tags: webpack

Is `require.main.filename` supported in webpack when targeting node?

> entry point of the current application can be obtained by checking require.main.filename.

Ref: https://nodejs.org/api/modules.html

Answer (score 0):

Looking at this commit, it seems like it is supported:

https://github.com/webpack/webpack/commit/8821f7bbf8328b0dcaa466257411575c27cc580b